# JavaScript sorting array elements with .map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I did map for the state

```
array.map(item =>
 <div>
   <p>{item.name}</p>
   <p>{item._status}</p>
 </div>
```

result: 
1. name: he, status: true. 
2. name: she, status: false. 
3. name: him, status: false. 
4. name: her, status: true. 
5. name: they, status: false.

I want that false status to be first,

thank you
result like this: 
1. name: she, status: false. 
2. name: him, status: false. 
3. name: they, status: false. 
4. name: he, status: true. 
5. name: they, status: true.

Comment: You have to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the array before maping

Comment: Hello Hakim! For future references, having more explanatory titles may help others identify the problem quicker. Reading "Javascript Array to First" didn't tell me much until I read your question. :)

Comment: Okay, thank you bro, It's Second times I'm asked here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can use `.sort()` first then `.map()`.

Try the following:

```
{
   array.sort((a, b) => (a._status === b._status) ? 0 : a._status ? 1 : -1).map(item =>
     <div>
       <p>{item.name}</p>
       <p>{item._status}</p>
     </div>
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Sort (by false `_status` first) and use `map`

```
array
  .sort(({ _status }) => (!_status ? -1 : 1))
  .map(item => (
    <div>
      <p>{item.name}</p>
      <p>{item._status}</p>
    </div>
  ));
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it's worked too, I had never think using sort before

Answer (score 0):

Sample application which can help you.

```
function App() {
  let array = [
    { id: 1, name: "Her", status: false },
    { id: 2, name: "Him", status: true },
    { id: 3, name: "They", status: true },
    { id: 4, name: "She", status: false },
    { id: 5, name: "He", status: true }
  ];
  let sorted = array.sort((a, b) => b.status - a.status);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {sorted.map(item => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <div>
            <span>{item.id}</span>
            <span>{item.name}</span>
          </div>
          <hr />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working example https://1z7rf.csb.app/